# Pulldown a pullup by default and then pullup again on an ESP2866

Tags: gpio, adafruit

I have an (Adafruit Feather Huzzah) ESP2866 WiFi module which has an (EN) pin to disable the 3v3 output on the chip. This pin is pulled up by default and normally you would just connect it to GND in order to switch off the 3v3 regulator (and disable the peripherals).

What I am trying to achieve is that when the ESP2866 is in "Deep Sleep" mode that the 3v3 output is disabled. Ideally if there was a pin that was pulled down by default when the device is asleep then I could just hook that into (EN) pin but I don't think this exists. However, there are pins that are pulled high by default when the device is fully awake.

What I was considering doing was using a high value resistor to create a weak pull down on this pin by using this to join GND to (EN). Then I would also directly join another pin that is pulled up when the module is on to "cancel out" the pull down. I have a feeling that I might need to end up using a transistor (or a few components) to toggle this low.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the Adafruit forums I have since discovered that pulling the EN pin also switches off the ESP2866 internal circuitry so it will never come back out of deep sleep.  On this basis there is no solution to this specific question as there will never be a high pin (without some form of external circuitry).

Thanks to those who bothered to read.